# Can we revoke and download authentication key(for Push notifications) if we lost old one?

Tags: ios, react-native, apple-push-notifications

In my Appstore account I have already created three authentication keys and I don't have any one of them. Now I am gonna publish one more app to app store which uses push notifications. Since I don't have any old autbentication key,

1.Can i revoke and download any old authentication key(which was already used for existing apps)?

2.If it is possible and do so, Will there be any issue to existing  apps?

Comment: where you able to create new after revoking one?

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is one active authentication key in your developer account, there shouldn't be any problem with the published apps. You should create a new one and download it, and only after doing so, revoke the old one.

Comment: I have already created two keys which is the limit, Hence I cannot create anymore. S0, Can I revoke old one  and download, And then uploading to all required iOS apps?